# Find month names for the last year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my ruby code I want to display all the months name of last 1 year. For example current date is `"April 2013"` then I want to display all months name from `"May 2012"` to `"April 2013"` such as `["May", "June", .., "April"]`. What is the best idea for this?

I tried:

```
<%= (1.year.ago.to_date.strftime("%B")..Date.today.strftime("%B")).map %> { |a| a } %>
```

But it gives: `["April"]`.

Comment: That is because `1.year.ago.to_date.strftime("%B")` and `Date.today.strftime("%B")` both return `"April"`. That gives you `("April".."April").map`

Comment: "then I want to display all months name from "May 2012" to "April 1013" such as ["May", "June", .., "May"]" can you fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rails you can do something like this:

```
<% 11.downto(0) do |i| %>
  <%= i.months.ago.strftime("%­B %Y") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Make sure to add %Y though as it was requested in the question.

Comment: `downto` takes a block, you can remove the `each` (if you are going to use it imperatively, that's it).

Answer (score 5):

```
11.downto(0).map { |m| m.months.ago.strftime("%B %Y") }
#=> ["May 2012", "June 2012", ..., "March 2013", "April 2013"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(0..11).map do |month|
    (11.months.ago + month.months).strftime("%B %Y")
end
```

Comment: This always starts in January, not May.

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity, there is not wide-known nifty [`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C) operator on `Date`:

```
(-12..0).inject([]) { 
  |agg, v| agg << Date::MONTHNAMES[(Date.today << v).month] 
}
```

or, even simplier:

```
(-12..0).map { |v| Date::MONTHNAMES[(Date.today << v).month] }
```

Comment: Using `MONTHNAMES` that's another way: `Date::MONTHNAMES.drop(1).rotate(Date.today.month)`.

Comment: @tokland Yes, I thought about it, but it’s restricted to 12 month back while my solution may be easily extended for any range. Anyway, it’s looking nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(0..11).each { |i|
  month = (Date.today.month + i) % 12 + 1;
  puts Date.new(Date.today.year - 1 + (month < Date.today.month ? 0 : 1), month).strftime("%B %Y")
}
```